# Access with breaking changes on Version 2206 (Recordset2.Fields returns DAO.Field3 instead of DAO.Field2) - Error 13

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

It looks like Microsoft introduced a breaking change with version 2206!  :-(

If you had code like

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset2
Dim fld as DAO.Field2

For Each fld in rs.Fields   '<- Code will break here, because Fields suddenly return Field3
   ... 
Next
```

This is a nightmare!
I can confirm that reverting to Version 2205 fixes the problem.

My questions:

- Has anybody an idea of how to fix the problem? (other than changing all the code)
- Anybody with some contact to MS to fix the mess?

Thanks for any help!

[image: Object browser for V 2205][image: Object browser for V 2206]

Comment: I'm still with 2205, but any references to `DAO.Field3`?

Comment: @Kostas K.: I just added object browser images for DAO. The first one is from V2205 and the second from V2206. Can't imagine what genius decided to change the default type...

Comment: try late binding, just Dim fld as Object, let the compiler/code apply the Field it needs.

Comment: Few people use multi-valued fields and `Recordset2` / `Field2`. Do you need it here? -- There is no documentation whatsoever to be found for `Field3`, so this change is kinda insane.

Comment: @RicardoA: We have an existing application using Fields in many locations. So I do have a problem with MS breaking an API! Of course we could use late binding, type checking etc. but that's not the point.

Comment: @Andre: No I don't need it here. The problem is that if you iterate over Fields in a DAO.Recordset that recordset suddenly returns Field3 objects. And you are right: till today I never heard of Field3. I guess it's safe to call it insane.

Comment: But you're iterating a Recordset2, not a Recordset. Can you try your code with `Dim rs as DAO.Recordset` and `Dim fld as DAO.Field` ? If that fails too, all hell will break loose.

Comment: Yes failing in our ERP application too, 30 Users are not able to start my application on a monday morning. We are net able to sell or ship anything now

Comment: @Andre: I did not have the chance to test moving from `Recordset2` to `Recordset`. But the point is that MS broke an existing API that was out in the wild for many many years.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how much you have used Office 365 in the last ca. 3 years - they are in the habit of doing that in Access. :(

Comment: Some links: [Access bugs](https://www.devhut.net/category/ms-access/ms-access-bugs/) (in case you wonder what I was talking about), [another 2206 bug](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/access-365-v2206-15330-20196-report-formatting-regression.323852/), [this issue there](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/another-access-365-v2206-bug-from-stackoverflow.323876/) - *The Access team is aware of and investigating this one. Seems to be a bit of a black hole so far, though.* whoa.

Comment: @Andre: Thanks for your link! Let's see what 'The Access team in aware of and investigating this one.' will bring - and WHEN.

Answer (score 3):

From MS:

> The simplest workaround for now is to change declarations of type `DAO.Field2` to `DAO.Field`.

> Field2 was added to support properties for multi-valued fields, *Field3 was added to support the Precision and Scale properties for decimal types*.  (You’ll note that there is also a Recordset2 object in the browser, for similar reasons).
>
> You don’t get intellisense for the extended properties if you declare as ‘Field’, but you can still access all the properties in code.

> When we make an update to an interface, we can’t update the existing interface, but must extend the existing interface.
> We are looking into whether we can improve the backward compatibility issue for cases where people explicitly declared variables to be of type Field2, rather than just Field.

Comment: thanks for your input. I will check this 'solution' as soon as I can. However, we are not talking about making to work something new, we are talking about breaking software that is installed on many computers. If MS keeps arbitrarily breaking APIs the only solution IMHO is to move away from MS...
@Gustav: Could you please post the source of your input?

Comment: OK. Please report your findings.