# Microsoft Access Attachment Recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, attachment, recordset

I have had a Microsoft Access application working for many years. However today the following code has stopped working.

```
    Dim Recordset2 As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim fieldAttachment As DAO.Field2
    stringSQLText = "SELECT [" & stringTable & "].ID" & vbCrLf
    stringSQLText = stringSQLText & "           , [" & stringTable & "].[" & stringFieldName & "]" & vbCrLf
    stringSQLText = stringSQLText & "        FROM [" & stringTable & "]" & vbCrLf
    stringSQLText = stringSQLText & "       WHERE ((([" & stringTable & "].ID)=" & longID & "));"
    Set Recordset2 = CurrentDatabase.OpenRecordset(stringSQLText, dbOpenSnapshot)
    'Error occurs here
    Set fieldAttachment = Recordset2(stringFieldName)
```

It reports the following error:

Error 13 Type mismatch

Could this be a result of an Office Update?

Has anybody else come across this problem?

My Access Version is Microsoft® Access® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2206 Build 16.0.15330.20216) 64-bit

Comment: A recent post of about 1 week ago had something similar. It seems that an update to Office is causing this issue, if you try to Dim fieldAttachment as Field3 or as just an Object it may fix it. Something with Field2 broke/changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831316/access-with-breaking-changes-on-version-2206-recordset2-fields-returns-dao-fiel

Comment: Thank you Ricardo that's exactly the problem and the workaround works

Answer (score 2):

Changed the code to use Field3 instead of Field2 and now works.